# ARM Cortex A9 - simulator with cycle accurate clock counts

Tags: arm, profiling, cortex-a

I am looking for a way of simulating the code compiled for Cortex A9 and obtaining the cycle accurate clock counts. Is there a simulator or a clever way to do so?

Comment: first off not possible as there are and can be compile time options that affect how many clocks it takes to do something, then there is the axi interface to the rest of the chip/system  that is chip vendor specific and how fast the system responds greatly affects performance, if not dominates performance/number of clocks things take to do.   If you work somewhere with a cortex-a9 based chip then talk to them you should be able to do this no problem.

Comment: arm does have programs where you can do such things, some are fpga based which may or may not help you others I think you do get something you can simulate.  might not be free no doubt you have to sign an nda at a minimum.